# Convert new line separated values from list to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of alphabets separated by `\n`.

```
mylist = ['a\n','b c d e\n', 'f g h i j\n', 'k l m\n', 'n o\n', 'p q r s\n', 't\n', 'u v w x y z\n']
```

I want to convert this into a dictionary of format:

```
mydict= {
a: {}
b: {c, d, e}
f: {g, h, i, j}
k: {l, m}
n: {o}
p: {q, r, s}
t: {}
u: {v, w, x, y, z}
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this in Python?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you mean for the values to be lists, not dictionaries?

Comment: I have the values in a list, as shown. I need to convert that list into a dictionary of the above given format.

Comment: The "above given format" isn't syntactically valid. In the line `b: {c,d,e}`, what do `c`, `d`, and `e` represent? Are they strings? Are they values? What do the brackets in `{c,d,e}` represent? Do you want that to be a set? A dict? A list?

Comment: thats what i meant, youre bracketing suggests that you want the value of each key to point to dicts but there are no key value pairs and it looks instead like you want them to be lists. (which is the answer that i gave)

Comment: I need it as a dictionary, not as a list. This would be used for a graph. So, in `b:{c,d,e}`, `c`, `d` and `e` are values and b is they key.

Comment: And what did *you* try to do before you asked this question?

Answer (score 5):

Something like the following should work:

```
{x[0]: set(x[1:]) for x in map(str.split, mylist)}
```

Answer (score 1):

dict comprehension:

```
>>> mydict = {x[0]:x[1:].strip().split() for x in mylist}
>>> mydict
{'p': ['q', 'r', 's'], 'n': ['o'], 'f': ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], 'a': [], 't': [], 'u': ['v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'], 'b': ['c', 'd', 'e'], 'k': ['l', 'm']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
mylist = ['a\n','b c d e\n', 'f g h i j\n', 'k l m\n', 'n o\n', 'p q r s\n', 't\n', 'u v w x y z\n']
```

You can use a dict of sets:

```
mydict={}
for e in mylist:
    li=e.split()
    mydict[li[0]]=set(li[1:])

>>> mydict
{'a': set([]), 'b': set(['c', 'e', 'd']), 'f': set(['i', 'h', 'j', 'g']), 'k': set(['m', 'l']), 'n': set(['o']), 'p': set(['q', 's', 'r']), 'u': set(['y', 'x', 'z', 'w', 'v']), 't': set([])}
```

And if you want your exact format:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(['{}: {}'.format(k, '{{{}}}'.format(', '.join(list(v)))) for k, v in mydict.items()]) 
a: {}
p: {q, s, r}
b: {c, e, d}
u: {y, x, z, w, v}
t: {}
f: {i, h, j, g}
k: {m, l}
n: {o}
```

Comment: Thanks! @Greg Hewgill.